# SSM Document use String and StringMap in invoke:Lambda step

Tags: aws-ssm

I'm trying to create and SSM document with two input parameters. One is a String and the other a MapList. I'm trying to use both as the Payload to invoke a lambda function. I keep seeing the error `InvalidDocumentContent: Parameter "Json" is "MAP_LIST" type and can't be used as a substring parameter.`

How, if possible can I use the MapList input as part of the Payload for invoking a Lambda Function

```
schemaVersion: '0.3'
parameters:
  Bool:
    type: String
    default: 'True'
  Json:
    type: MapList
    description: Json
mainSteps:
  - inputs:
      FunctionName: my-lambda-function
      Payload: '{"Bool": {{Bool}}, "Json": "{{ Json }}"}'
    name: Step1
    action: 'aws:invokeLambdaFunction'
```